# Perf API introducing many kernel cache read accesses

Tags: c, linux, perf

I'm using the perf syscall (perf_event_open) to monitor a demo. The simplified code is as follows:

```
  int *ptr;
  ptr = (int*)malloc(512 * 1024 * 1024 * sizeof(int)); // Allocate memory for an integer

  if (ptr == NULL) {
      printf("Memory allocation failed\n");
      return 1;
  }

  srand(time(NULL));



  //preload
  for(int i = 0; i < 512 * 1024 * 1024; i++){
      int random_number = rand();
      ptr[i] = random_number;
  }

  perf_start_measurement_group(group); //start measurement of cache read access in kernel mode

  int test = 0;
  for(int i = 0; i < 512 * 1024 * 1024; i+=1){
    // test += test;
      acc += ptr[i];
  } 

  perf_stop_measurement_group(group); //stop measurements of cache read access in kernel mode
```

The perf_start_measurement_group(group) and perf_stop_measurement_group(group) are user-defined. You can consider them as the start and end of event counting. Specifically, the perf_event_open I called is like:

```
//The attribute monitors read access/miss of LLC, with user_space excluded
//I used a group to monitor multiple events (LLC read access and miss count)
perf_event_open(attribute, 0, -1, group, 0);
```

Then I got about 80000 kernel-level LLC read access counts. This is wired because there shouldn't be that many kernel-level operations in that for-loop. Actually, if I change the for-loop to:

```
  for(int i = 0; i < 512 * 1024 * 1024; i+=1){
    // test += test;
      acc += ptr[0];
  }
```

Or even

```
  for(int i = 0; i < 512 * 1024 * 1024; i+=1){
      test += test;
  }
```

The number of user-level LLC read does reduce but the number of kernel-level access remains unchanged. So I doubt the perf API results in the high number of kernel-level access.
So my question is.

1. Is the perf API responsible for this?
2. If I want to ignore the kernel-level events introduced perf, but monitor other kernel-level events, what can I do?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Enable optimizations and disassemble to see if anything odd is going on, such as function calls on the asm level etc. Staring at the C code won't do you much good.

Comment: Kernel counts include interrupt handlers, since the kernel's per-core `current` variable is still your process while they're running.  Long-running loops will accumulate counts for device driver code that ran in interrupts.  I don't think there's a way to get the kernel to save/restore PMU counters when entering an IRQ handler; that would probably be slow.